# Using VS2019, .Net 5.0, Winforms.Wasm 1.0.19137.60 Nuget package - produces unhandled Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionExceptions

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, webassembly, .net-5

I am trying to port 6 class libraries developed under .Net 4.5.2 to .Net 5.00 using VS 2019.  I chose .Net 5.00 (and VS 2019) as my final goal is to deliver the solution as a web assembly. I have set the target framework for each of the libaries to .NET 5.0.

One of my class libraries uses Winforms so I have downloaded the Nuget package Winforms.Wasm (1.0.191137.60) by Roozbeh Gh into VS 2019.

On building I initially got the error:

```
1>C:\Users\howar_000\.nuget\packages\winforms.wasm\1.0.19137.60\build\netstandard2.0\Winforms.Wasm.targets(13,5): error : 
Unhandled Exception: Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
... at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters) 
... at Driver.Import(String ra, AssemblyKind kind)    
... at Driver.Run(String[] args)    
... at Driver.Main(String[] args)
```

I was able to get past this problem by adding:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

as per instructions I found on the Winforms.Wasm GIT repository recommended by Roozbeh Gh.

```
1>C:\Users\howar_000\.nuget\packages\winforms.wasm\1.0.19137.60\build\netstandard2.0\Winforms.Wasm.targets(13,5): error : 
Unhandled Exception: Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Formats.Asn1, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' 1>C:\Users\howar_000\.nuget\packages\winforms.wasm\1.0.19137.60\build\netstandard2.0\Winforms.Wasm.targets(13,5): error :    at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters) 
... at Driver.Import(String ra, AssemblyKind kind) 
... at Driver.Import(String ra, AssemblyKind kind) 
... at Driver.Import(String ra, AssemblyKind kind) 
... at Driver.Import(String ra, AssemblyKind kind) 
... at Driver.Run(String[] args)
```

i.e. it just moved the problem along to another library distributed along with Winforms.Wasm.  I have also tried to explicitly exclude the Nuget version of the System.Formats.Asn.dll but this hasnt worked either.

I realise the problem is that the Nuget Winforms.Wasm package includes netstardard2.0 libraries so that the package download is as a complete standalone distribution.  Further that VS 2019 MSBuild is identifying a clash with the dotnet net5.0 distribution.

I have done a lot of investigation trying to resolve this problem - even overwriting
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Formats.Asn1.dll
with
C:\Users\howar_000.nuget\packages\system.formats.asn1\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Formats.Asn1.dll
and visa versa but to no avail.

But reading through swathes of literature on the web, I came to the realisation that this is a recurring problem that has plagued developers trying to use VS with .Net and Nuget packages for some time.  Surely either Microsoft need to change the implementation of VS MSBuild to accommodate Nuget packages or Nuget package writers need to come up with a VS compliant distribution - rather than leaving developers spending many hours trying to establish work arounds and understand the inner works of VS MSBuild.

I am thinking of moving away from VS 2019 to use the Mono Developer toolkit - I will let you know how I get on.

Any help/suggestions on how best to migrate .Net 4.5.2 assemblies that use Nuget packages to equivalent web assemblies would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am experiancing exactly the same issue, have you solved it?